# How to test a REDUX action containg a time reference

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

### Context

I am currently testing some REDUX actions for my React application. One of these actions stores the time when some data was retrieved, but I am unsure about the way to test the action.

At the moment, this is a rough equivalent of the action:

```
export const receiveFruit = (fruitName, fruitData) => {
    return {
        type: RECEIVE_MAP,
        receivedAt: Date.now(),
        fruitName: fruitName,
        data: fruitData ? fruitData : "no_data"
    }
};
```

### Testing

Now, regarding the testing I use JEST, but perhaps there are other ways to test the above action. What I would typically do is something like in the [documentation on testing with REDUX](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#action-creators):

```
test("Should create an action to receive a fruit", () => {
    const fruitName = "banana";
    const fruitData = {isTasty: true, isBlue: false};
    const receivedAt = Date.now(); // <- Here this won't match the other action of course
    const expectedAction = {
        type: actions.RECEIVE_MAP,
        fruitName: fruitName,
        receivedAt: receivedAt,
        data: fruitData
    };
    expect(actions.receiveFruit(fruitName, fruitData)).toEqual(expectedAction)
});
```

Of course this will fail the test, because of the difference of time between the two actions. As a consequence I have added a "receivedAt" parameter for the action. So it is possible to provide a value for the received time to match that of the test time, so this so far to cover the tests:

```
export const receiveFruit = (fruitName, fruitData, receivedAt=Date.now()) => {
    return {
        type: RECEIVE_MAP,
        receivedAt: receivedAt,
        fruitName: fruitName,
        data: fruitData ? fruitData : "no_data"
    }
};
```

While this solution works, it is inelegant, error prone if somebody makes some wrong input in the codebase even though there is documentation. I believe there might be a "smarter" way to do this, like to freeze time or something, but I don't can't find a way to do it properly.

So, **how to test properly such REDUX action containing a time reference ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock functionality like always:

```
const mockNowFn = 
jest.spyOn(Date,'now').mockImplementation(() => 
1573149880417);
// ... write your tests here
mockNowFn.mockRestore();
```

but there are more ways for doing this you can read about them here:
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2234